# "error_message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources." using WooCommerce API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

When requesting the test API, getting the following response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "error_code": "",
            "error_message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources."
        }
    ]
}
```

The credentials are OK, REST API keys have both read/write permissions. I tried with newly generated API keys, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go

The original `.htaccess` looked like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then I changed it to the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and now it works !!!